# dart polymer - catch toggle event - button inside paper-scaffold. polymer_20 error

Tags: button, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I am getting error:

*Inline event handlers are only supported inside declarations of [polymer-element]. See http://goo.gl/5HPeuP#polymer_20 for details*

My code is:

```
<body unresolved>
  <paper-scaffold> <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed" >
    <core-toolbar>Test</core-toolbar> 
       <core-menu> 

       <div id='xtoggle'>Edit
       <paper-toggle-button  label='xlabel' on-change='ontoggle()'> 
       </paper-toggle-button> </div>
```

i.e. it is not allowed to have an **on-change** for the **button**. So, how do I catch these events please?
Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can subscribe to the toggle's `core-change` event like this -

```
var toggle = document.querySelector('paper-toggle-button');

toggle.addEventListener('core-change', function() {
  console.log("Toggled!");
});
```

Please see this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gapop/2/) for a working example.

Comment: Or just change `on-change` to `core-change` in HTML.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, thanks but I tried `core-change` and it doesn't work? Also, `onchange` works.

Comment: I didn't look at `paper-toggle-button`, I just thought when the imperative `toggle.addEventListener('core-change', ...)` works then the declartive `core-change="..."` should work too. I wonder what you mean by `onchange` works. With `onchange` you can only add JavaScript event handlers but not Dart. I just saw that you need to do `core-change="{{ontoggle}}"` instead of `core-change="ontoggle()"` (or `on-change="{{ontoggle}}"` (depending on what's the actual event name.

Comment: Ahh, I just remembered it's for dart! You are right. But would you be able to do inline handler like `core-change` outside of polymer element?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inline handler". Dart doesn't have any support for inline handlers. Either you use Polymer (or some other framework which has some kind of binding support) or you add the handler imperatively.

Comment: Yes, correct. That's why I suppose by changing to `core-change` would still not work 'cause the toggle is not inside a polymer element?

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer - Gunter and Justin for the help and conversation. This worked for me:<br>    toggle.addEventListener('core-change', (event)=> myfunc());    
<br>Cheers, Steve